# Regex: Ignore order of capture groups and capture only last occurrence

Tags: regex

Let's say we have the following string:

```
1|order=asc|type=1
```

We need to create regex that will parse it to parameters assuming that string always should start with number and will (optionally) have parameters (order, asc) in any order. Also it may have 3 and more parameters but let's keep 2 here for simplicity.
For instance these are the string that regex will understand:

```
1
1|order=asc|type=1
1|type=1|order=asc
```

I have the following expression that does this job:

```
(?<id>^\w+)((?:\|type=(?<type>\w+))|(?:\|order=(?<order>\w+))){0,2}
```

This is [demo](https://regex101.com/r/pUo1S1/2/) link to my regex

But the issue is that it allows duplicates.

If we have the following string it will not match `order` parameter at all:

```
1|type=1|type=2|order=asc
```

Ideally we should have the following groups from regex above:

- id:1
- type:2 (as it should capture last occurrence)
- order:asc

Comment: Maybe something like `^(?<id>\w+)(?:\|(?:type=(?<type>\w+)|order=(?<order>\w+)))+$` will do? See https://regex101.com/r/uZJfkp/1

Comment: To catch the `<id>` from the 1st input you would need `*` instead of `+`. @WiktorStribiżew. Nice solution though. Post it?

Comment: Yes, I should use `*` with that last group.

Comment: If you need to support unknown params, you may add the `\w+=\w*` pattern as an alternative, `.*` matches too much. See `^(?<id>\w+)(?:\|(?:type=(?<type>\w+)|order=(?<order>\w+)|num=(?<num>\d+)|status=(?<status>\w+)|\w+=\w*))*\|?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQ7OCn/5)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?<id>\w+)(?:\|(?:type=(?<type>\w+)|order=(?<order>\w+)))*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uZJfkp/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - string start
- `(?<id>\w+)` - Group "id": one or more word chars
- `(?:\|(?:type=(?<type>\w+)|order=(?<order>\w+)))*` - zero or more repetitions of

  - `\|` - a `|` char
  - `(?:type=(?<type>\w+)|order=(?<order>\w+))` - either of

    - `type=(?<type>\w+)|` - `type=` text, then Group "type" capturing one or more word chars, and then an OR operator
    - `order=` - text `order=` and then
    - `(?<order>\w+)` - Group "order": one or more word chars
- `$` - string end.

The capturing groups inside the `(?:...)*` repeated group will keep re-writing the group values each time they capture a string and thus the last occurrences will be kept.

You can enhance this regex by adding more groups inside the second non-capturing group. For example, adding `num` and `status` is as easy as

```
^(?<id>\w+)(?:\|(?:type=(?<type>\w+)|order=(?<order>\w+)|num=(?<num>\d+)|status=(?<status>\w+)))*$
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TQ7OCn/1/).

Comment: @Thefourthbird We just need to remember that this trick [does not work](https://regex101.com/r/TQ7OCn/2) in JavaScript and ECMAScript in general where non-participating groups are re-initialized with an empty string upon each capture (and only the last group captured actually is populated with a value, the rest will be empty).

Comment: Good to know, I was not aware of that. Still a good answer.